# Using SQL Query Designer Pros and Cons

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-designer

I've seen many developers using SQL Query designer to build queries rather than writing it from scratch.

What are the **pros** and **cons** of using SQL query designer instead of writing manual queries ?

How it effects for optimizations and maintenance of queries.

Comment: Honestly: I can't think of any advantage (and I would be suspicious of a developer that needs one)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name most of the times I've seen queries generated from designer is lil bit messy

Comment: @tarzanbappa I guess your question is primary opinion-based. I have seen many query's generated this way and *lit bit messy* is not the word to describe it :) The main PRO - you just put all you need - link it to each other - Tadam - query is ready. Main CON - this query's are hard to read and understand, they may add some logic - you don't need (they can be rewritten in way to work faster).

Answer (score 0):

Cons: you can't write complex logic and queries by designer.

Pros: If you are not familiar with sql concepts even don't know about CRUD operation than only designer will help you....